# Git, find tracked version of untracked file?

Tags: git, file, search, version, diff

For example you make a solid copy of a tracked file. Than you make some changes on the tracked version. Than i would like to find what commit is closest, maybe even equal, to my untracked version of the file inside the repository which the file was copied from. Is it even possible ?

I know the best way is to have the copy of the file/repository contain its own git history. but in this case its not possible.

For info, it is possible to have the same working tree and file name.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the closest commit is probably non-trivial because it involves somehow measuring the similarity between your file and the commit you're comparing to.

But if your copy is exactly the same as the file in some commit, it's not too difficult to go through the file's commit history and compare against your copy. Something like the following Bash script (not tested) should work if you run it from the Git repository folder like:

```
./compare.sh folder/subfolder/file.c ~/backup/copy-of-file.c
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TRACKED="$1"
UNTRACKED="$2"

for commit in `git log --format=%H "$1"`; do
    contents="$(git show $commit:"$TRACKED")"
    diff "$UNTRACKED" <(echo "$contents") > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" == 0 ]; then
        echo "$UNTRACKED is the same as commit "$commit""
        exit 0
    fi
done

echo "No exact match found"
```

Comment: That is the solution i want to evade. I know its possible to find the commit with less differences possible, by searching and comparing the sort diff values.
I very much want to have the less system call/processing/loops possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found some optional solution myself, i wont say it is the one i will be using or it is the best that i have, but i would like to share it here in case.

Its is called "**Keyword Expansion**" and all what it does is firing a script when a file is checkout. The script, called "**smudge**" you can define what will it do, would for example inject the last 10 commits for the file in to the header.
There is second script called, "**clean**" that you make sure does reverse of the "smudge" so git knows what part of the file he have to ignore in the diff.

Yep, on the remote that you will push into the change is not made, due to "**clean**", but whenever you checkout the file gets edited by the script so you can have the modified part.

From here it gives me some sort of trace of the file, and its history when i would not be using git.

Here is the link:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion